# Translated letter of recommendation from employer

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, recommendation-letter, translations, france

I live and work full time in the United States. I will be applying to graduate school in France through CampusFrance. All documents, apparently including letters of recommendation, are to be translated into French (by a certified translator). This seems to preclude the possibility of my not having seen the letter of recommendation before it is sent, which I understand to be important for the documents. One possibility would be to send the documents to a translator without opening them, and blindly sending the translated version along to the institution, which seems risky. What is the best course of action in this case?

Comment: _This seems to preclude the possibility of my not having seen the letter of recommendation before it is sent_ Was the double negative intentional?

Comment: _One possibility would be to send the documents to a translator without opening them_ This assumes document authors will send them directly to you, which is unusual (for letters of recommendation).

Comment: Why is it _risky_ to _blindly send[] the translated version_?

Comment: Yes, the double negative was intentional. To clarify, I should not see the letter myself, but it seems that I may have to see it.

My concern is that I wouldn't be able to verify the translator's work; is this a valid concern?

Comment: I don't think you should be concerned with the work product of a _**certified** translator_

Answer (score 4):

Ask the professor to send the letter to the translator with instructions to return it back to the professor. Make separate arrangements to pay the translator. Then the prof can directly send the translation. And the prof can even verify it a bit if needed.

You don't need to be in the document loop at all.